# Elm: How do I display a list of strings in an HTML list?

Tags: elm

I'm writing an [elm](http://elm-lang.org/) program that should format its output in an HTML list. The function I want takes,

```
inputs = ["first", "second", "third"]
```

and outputs some kind of Elm `Element` that is essentially,

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

Sadly, I can't find any built-in functions to do this. Perhaps the `markdown` syntax could be extended to take Mustache-like templates,

```
[markdown|
{{#inputs}}
* {{text}}
{{/inputs}}
]
```

(sorry I'm not sure what the correct Mustache syntax is for an array-of-strings, instead of array-of-objects).

Raw HTML element emitting would also be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The word you're looking for is "markdown interpolation" and it is something that was discussed a while back when I complained about something very similar to this. Maybe this will help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-discuss/markdown$20interpolation/elm-discuss/HXMZRmrQdzI/Z2hzt8LpxYwJ

Answer (score 37):

Do you want to render in an element (i.e. canvas) or truly as html. If the latter, then you can use `elm/html` and

```
renderList : List String -> Html msg
renderList lst =
    ul []
        (List.map (\l -> li [] [ text l ]) lst)
```

or in piping style

```
renderList : List String -> Html msg
renderList lst =
    lst
       |> List.map (\l -> li [] [ text l ])
       |> ul []
```

or in point-free style

```
renderList : List String -> Html msg
renderList lst =
    lst
       |> List.map (li [] << List.singleton << text)
       |> ul []
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is what the OP really wanted given his comments about "having the browser (+ css) format it". The thing is, he asked for help formatting it as an Elm `Element`, which is not what he actually wanted (a plain HTML element). So yours was the first answer that addressed what he really *wanted*, as opposed to what he *asked for*.

Comment: He probably didn't know the Html lib existed. It's now in core, too.

Comment: If you want to propose an alternative, use a second (complete) block of code. It is confusing to read here.

Comment: `List.map`, just to be pedantic / helpful to future noobs like myself

Comment: Really liked the nice piping style one.

Answer (score 6):

When you start writing a function, it's helpful to define your function's [signature](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/). The signature is written on the line before the function definition. The signature you want is:

```
toHtmlList : List String -> Html msg -- here's the signature
toHtmlList strings =                 -- here's the start of the function body
  ???
```

The output of this function has type `Html msg`, which is provided by the [elm-html](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/latest) package. You add this to your project by running the command `$ elm-package install elm-lang/html` from your project root.

Once that is installed, add a statement to import `Html` into your elm file, and implement the function. Here's a working implementation:

**StringList.elm**

```
import Html exposing (..)

inputs = ["first", "second", "third"]

toHtmlList : List String -> Html msg
toHtmlList strings =
  ul [] (List.map toLi strings)

toLi : String -> Html msg
toLi s = 
  li [] [ text s ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I don't think Elm has a built-in `Element` for lists. I'm not sure whether that's intentional because you can roll your own*, or if it's just that nobody ever needed a non-static list of things before. (HTML lists are used on the [elm-lang.org](http://elm-lang.org) website, but those are static lists that I think are defined in MarkDown)

Markdown interpolation with moustache syntax was [implemented](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/HXMZRmrQdzI/discussion) but I'm not sure on it's status. And at any rate it was not as powerful as the thing you're describing.

Emitting raw HTML is not part of the philosophy of Elm's `Graphics` API. The idea is that the current HTML/CSS/JavaScript way of writing websites and web-applications is a mess, even with all the libraries etc. built on top of it. So Elms way is to put a layer of abstraction over it so you can just talk about rectangular `Element`s that naturally stack horizontally and vertically (with `flow`*), and free-form `Form`s that can be put in a `collage` (which is again a rectangular `Element`).

*(see Daniëls answer for one with bullets, this one is just bare-bones):

```
inputs = ["first", "second", "third"]
main = flow down <| map plainText inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bullet list in Elm using a collage:

```
bullet : Element
bullet = collage 12 20 [circle 3 |> filled black]

render : [String] -> Element
render = flow down . map (beside bullet . plainText)

main : Element
main = render ["first", "second", "third"]
```

Live example: http://share-elm.com/sprout/538e460fe4b07afa6f981ab6

Comment: yeahhhhh, that's not as nice as having the browser (+ css) format it

Comment: Why do you think it is not as nice?

Comment: text wrapping, lack of css styling, trying to do layout manually (note: arbitrary constants '12' and '20') vs. having the browser do it automatically, nesting elements ...

Comment: The thing is, in Elm you can abstract either those all away or have complete control over the visual appearance. 
You could change '12', '20', and '3' to be dependent on the size of the plainText for example.
You can't do this in HTML / CSS, because there are no functions (unless you use a preprocessor or use JavaScript).

Comment: Yes, I'd rather give up control to have a lot of basic things--which are unrelated to my application functionality--taken care of by the browser/css. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: share-elm.com doesn't appear to be a valid url anymore